# PostgreSQL: count number of occurrences of a value in a column using the last entry per day, per name

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a table which looks like this:

```
id |   name   |   time               |    measurement
---+----------+----------------------+----------------
10 |   abc    | 2015-02-13 20:12:34  |        2
9  |   abc    | 2015-02-13 19:12:34  |        1
8  |   xyz    | 2015-02-13 18:12:34  |        1
7  |   abc    | 2015-02-13 17:12:34  |        0
6  |   abc    | 2015-02-12 20:12:34  |        0
5  |   pqr    | 2015-02-12 19:12:34  |        2
4  |   pqr    | 2015-02-12 18:12:34  |        1
3  |   xyz    | 2015-02-12 17:12:34  |        0
2  |   pqr    | 2015-02-12 16:12:34  |        1
1  |   abc    | 2015-02-12 15:12:34  |        0
```

I need to select only the last entry per day, per name for the last N days, where N is a constant:

```
id |   name   |   time               |    measurement
---+----------+----------------------+----------------
10 |   abc    | 2015-02-13 20:12:34  |        2
8  |   xyz    | 2015-02-13 18:12:34  |        1
6  |   abc    | 2015-02-12 20:12:34  |        0
5  |   pqr    | 2015-02-12 19:12:34  |        2
3  |   xyz    | 2015-02-12 17:12:34  |        0
```

And then count how many times each different value in `measurement` appears per day:

```
day         |   value   |  count
------------+-----------+----------
2015-02-13  |     2     |    1
2015-02-13  |     1     |    1
2015-02-12  |     2     |    1
2015-02-12  |     0     |    1
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3429e/3)

```
select
    to_char(day, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as day,
    measurement as value,
    count(*) as count
from (
    select distinct on (1, name)
        date_trunc('day', time) as day, measurement
    from t
    order by 1, name, time desc
) s
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2 desc
```